# software for Nullstellensatz certificate of infeasibility

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computational-mathematics

I was wondering if anyone could recommend software to construct a real Nullstellensatz certificate that a system of polynomial equations has no real solution.  The system of about 20 polynomials equations is cubic at most.  I was interested in something that applied, or is similar to, (Nullstellensatz Linear Algebra (NulLA) Algorithm) as described here https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/margulies/papers/nulla_issac.pdf

My understanding is that if the certificate is of degree 1 then I'll have about 400 linear equations, but that if its of degree 2 then this explodes to 8000 or so.  Hence the need for some purpose built software.

Any suggestions or approaches much appreciated (I have a science not math background).

thanks

Comment: Margulies gave a talk on this a while back. [Here is the webpage](https://simons.berkeley.edu/talks/susan-margulies-2016-03-31) it may lead to some useful resources. I however do not think there are any standard cas packages around as this is a fresh research field. I believe you may be able to use current implementations if you can get a hold of them. That's all I can really say about this.